# How can you refresh multiple excel files at once?

Tags: excel, refresh

I use an access database to push data into about 300 files every month. The only problem is, in order to update each file I have to go into each one individually and hit "refresh all" as each excel file has multiple tabs with data pushed from access.

Just seeing if there was anything that I could do to save some time and "refresh all" of these excel sheets at once.